# Give a class to specific Page in Main Menu in Typo3

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I want to achieve having a menu with 2 levels, and some should always be expanded - some shouldn't. Is there any way I can hand over a class or something, if possible set up in the backend, to be able to choose which menu links should be expanded?

For example:

1. Menu Link 1 with no subitems
2. Menu Link 2 with subitems expandable (sublinks only visible on click)
3. Menu Link 3 with subitems always expanded (sublinks always visible)

   - Sub link 1
   - Sub link 2

Comment: I'd add a checkbox to the pages table and use it in fluid

Comment: do you have a link to the docs or anything else where I can find information about how to do this?

Comment: Here you can find a German tutorial for extending the page table 
https://www.sebkln.de/tutorials/typo3-datenbanktabellen-um-neue-felder-erweitern/

Answer (score 0):

In general you need to add a class to the link or the `li`tag so CSS or javascript can decide which parts are visible.

A similar question would be to have some submenus not rendered at all, but as you want these submenus to be visible on a click they must be rendered anyway. so it is only the question how to get this information into the rendered menu. it should be a flag which can change the visibility. that could be done with CSS and javascript.

You can sore this information in the `pages`record, where you can use any otherwise unused field (example would be `layout`). The realisation depends on the way you generate the menu.

Meanwhile you have two options:

1. classic: with typoscript
2. fluid: menu-processor

With both options you can add classes to the menu-items, where the JS can work on.